Disable AutoTransactionBehavior in EF Core to MongoDB
I'm developing an API locally that makes calls to a locally-hosted MongoDB (community). I'm constantly seeing this pop up in my logs:

System.NotSupportedException: The MongoDB EF Core Provider now uses transactions to ensure all updates in a SaveChanges operation are applied together or not at all. Your current MongoDB server configuration does not support transactions and you should consider switching to a replica set or load balanced configuration. If you are sure you do not need save consistency or optimistic concurrency you can disable transactions by setting 'Database.AutoTransactionBehavior = AutoTransactionBehavior.Never' on your DbContext.

I am getting DB context from IDBContextFactory, and while I can set this behavior on every context that I pull from my factory, I would prefer that the factory provide me with a context that has this value already configured.
Here's my existing implementation of the DBContextFactory in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MongoContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMongoDB(
        connectionString: mongoSection["ConnectionString"] ?? "",
        databaseName: mongoSection["Database"] ?? "");
});

How do I configure this factory so that the context being provided to my services is already configured with context.Database.AutoTransactionBehavior = AutoTransactionBehavior.Never?

Are you connecting to a 'standalone' mongod process? If you 'convert it to a replica set', which basically means to restart the process with an additional configuration flag and then run the rs.initiate() command one time, then that should solve the database configuration error that you are getting. Notice that your database would still be just a single process (which is not recommended) but it would be in 'replica set mode' which supports transactions
